# How to properly hide MySQL credentials in a python project on replit.com?

Tags: python, mysql, replit

I haven't posted in a while, but I need help with something. I have MySQL credentials that I need to use in a python project to connect to a database on PHPMyAdmin hosted by [Freesqldatabase](https://freesqldatabase.com). this is the code I use to connect to it:

```py
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(
                                user=*username*, 
                                password=*password*,
                                host=*host*(sql9.freesqldatabase.com),
                                database=*database*)
```

I have the credentials and the credentials are correct, I just don't know how I could hide the credentials from the user that plays the repl project, since I uploaded it to the community on replit.

Basically, what happens is when the user plays the repl, the project is forked without the user knowing. This is an issue because I use the `simplecrypt` library to decrypt the data from a separate `data.txt` file, but the user could actually fork the repl and manipulate the script to get the data.

I have also tried the secret `os.environ['key']` solution, but the os environment variables aren't forked with the project, so the user can't connect to the database through the repl project like they're supposed to.

I looked into this, and the only other solution I could find is to use a `.env` file, but that functionality is deprecated.

**Is there any other way I could do this?**

Comment: _phpMyAdmin credentials?_ phpMyAdmin is a tool written in PHP to help beginners and experts alike maintain MySQL databases more easily than using the command line. You are talking about MySQL credentials

Comment: DOes python not have an `include` functionality that will allow you to include a file with variables set to the uid and pwd? Then you can leave that file out of your repo so each cloner has to make there own